# Cannot compile GLFW after building it in QtCreator with CMake (Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, glfw

I have [downloaded](https://www.glfw.org/download.html) the GLFW source package for building the library. 
In the QtCreator IDE, I go to `File/Open file or project` and select the `CMakeLists.txt` of GLFW. The project is built and the resulting files stored in a certain folder.

The next step is to compile the library to get the `.a` files (we want to create a static library that could be used by another application). However, the compilation never ends, and the compile output shows `"Persisting CMake state..."` forever.

I have made my research but cannot find an answer to this. I'm not an expert on CMake or QtCreator IDE.

I could build the project for MVS (Microsoft Visual Studio) in Windows with `cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017" path/to/CMakeLists.txt`
And then compile the resulting MVS project with MVS.

I could do the same on Linux using only the command line (`cmake path/to/CMakeLists.txt`, `make all`).

However, I find these problem with QtCreator...

Comment: Googling indicates that this was a known [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-16258) in QtCreator. What version of QtCreator are you using?

Comment: I'm using QtCreator 4.8.2. So this is not affected by that bug.